# Боковая навигация Android

Tags: xml, menu, android, java, slider

Читал статью про боковую навигацию в Android, очень эффективно, но нужно **Android 4.3** а  меня **4.1**, погрустил и хватит. Но тут когда открывал новый **Layoult** с **Intent**, заметил как один **layoult** сдвигается и плавно 2-й сбоку приезжает.

Может есть таки способ в **Android 4.1** реализовать такое меню(боковую навигацию) чтоб не очень сложно.

Мне нужно при сдвиге от левой части экрана к центру открывать новое **меню/layoult** с своими компонентами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) только support.v4  подключите и на младших полетит

Comment: А что будет если я потяну меню на телефоне с Android 2.3 ? Ошибка или ничего?

Comment: v4 = API4 = 1.6. будет работать

Comment: Спасибо всем!.